# How can I get a round button?

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to have a round button control in WinForms, how might I accomplish this? A third-party control or code sample would be fine.

Answer (score 21):

You can make your own pretty easily, the Region property makes it simple.  Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox onto a form.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class RoundButton : Button {
    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e) {
        using (var path = new GraphicsPath()) {
            path.AddEllipse(new Rectangle(2, 2, this.Width - 5, this.Height - 5));
            this.Region = new Region(path);
        }
        base.OnResize(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Drop it from the top of the toolbox after compiling.

Comment: Why not overriding OnPaint method ?

Answer (score 2):

[telerik RadButtons for WinForms](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/buttons.aspx) maybe?

- [Rounded winform Button](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/winforms/ui-controls/rounded-winform-button.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

add custom drawing in OnPaint event handler.

Answer (score 2):

Use WPF if its still early in the project and you can still switch

Comment: It's never to late to switch to WPF!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest following two DLL files: PresentationCore.dll and PresentationFramework.dll

It's more commonly known as [Windows Presentation Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx) (WPF), and can easily be used to [make round buttons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613598.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably have to create an image with your rounded corners specification, and use it on an image button to achieve what you want.