# How To Create A Circle Shaped TextBox?

Tags: winforms, textbox, geometry

i created a small game - WinForm Application  ( Bingo for those of you who know the game )
and i need some help please.
i was wondering how can i create a textbox that is a circle shaped.
and i do not meen to round the edges . 
my goal is to show a 2-digit number in this textbox that represents the current ball that came up .
i wanted to make it circle because of the shape of a bingo ball .

can this be done ? or can you give (and show) me a different solution ?

i added my current view of the game :

[Players Screen](http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/8413/81894946.jpg)

thanks alot !

Comment: A textbox makes little sense and won't work well, you don't want the user to type the number.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get a round button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896342/how-can-i-get-a-round-button)

Comment: please see the attached picture called "Players Screen". it is a winform application .

Comment: Hans , the game is automaticlly . not manual. 
i am using an array filled with numbers , and every couple of seconds it shows a different number

Comment: Well, exactly, so you don't need a textbox.  A PictureBox or Label will do fine as well, use the Region property as shown in the dup.

Answer (score 0):

You do not actually have to have a circular label/textbox.

Get a picture of a circle in the size/color you want.
Add the circle as an image control,
then add a label on top of it with the number.

The label should have a transparent background color.

Comment: my app is based on 2 screens. 1 form is shown in the main screen. and the other form (the players form) is show on the screen the is attached to the main computer . and all my controls in the players form , including the textbox resize themselfs according to the screens resolution. wouldn't be a problem  ?

Comment: You need to calculate the radius of the circle (if you resize it), and make sure the label is in the middle of it.. assuming dimensions of the label are X, and the radius of the circle is R, then the size of x would be : x = sqrt(2 * r^2)