# Visual C#: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#

I'm getting this error after trying to add a WMP reference to my program:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Hangman, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (My project is called Hangman.)**

I embedded the player on my form following [these guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383953%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

At the top of my form I included

```
using WMP;
```

And I used it in my code like this:

```
WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
wplayer.settings.setMode("loop", true);
wplayer.URL = @"E:\Hangman\Music\Jingle.mp3";
wplayer.controls.play();
wmpMusicPlayer.Size = new Size(0, 0);
```

After getting the error, I deleted the embedded player and the references to it in the solution explorer. I'm still getting the error. Any ideas on how to fix this?

**Update:**

I'm getting a new error on one of my forms:

> Could not find type 'Hangman.RoundBtn'. Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced. IF this type is a part of your development project, make sure that the project has been successfully built using settings for your current platform or Any CPU.

I created a new class (by right clicking on my project and adding a class) called RoundBtn following the most upvoted recommendation here:

[How can I get a round button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896342/how-can-i-get-a-round-button)

I'm using this in place of all the buttons in my forms. I do not see it under 'References' in the Solution Explorer and can't find it in the Reference Manager either. I do see the RoundBtn.cs file, though, and the code that creates the personalized button.

Comment: Turn on fusion logging and see if it gives you more information about what DLL is missing: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx

Comment: I'm not able to do that since I'm using a school computer. I can open the assembly binding log viewer, but can't do anything with it.

Comment: A little more information on your solution structure may help solve the problem.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Here is a screenshot of the solution explorer: http://imgur.com/ael6eRq

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual C#: Class not recognized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415508/visual-c-class-not-recognized)

Comment: this is now a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415508/visual-c-class-not-recognized  Please close this one and use the other, more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all reference related to media player which you manually added. Then clean the solution and just drag and drop the Media player tool to your form then it will automatically add all the references which  related to player. Later you can delete that control and you can use your code.